# Spring boot elastic - set default date format

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We would like to start storing a very large hierarchy of classes into elastic.

We marked their base class with **@Document** annotation so we could store the entire hierarchy in elastic

Many of the classes there has **java.util.Date** fields.

Unfortunately - the default mapping for these fields is a **Long** number on elastic. (we use **spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch 2.4.2**)

The problem is resolved when we mark these fields with the annotation:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date,format = DateFormat.date_time)
```

Is there a default way we can set this default format to all the mapping in the hierarchy ?
We would like to avoid from going over hundreds of classes and mark their fields with this annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar w/ spring-boot but generally speaking, if I have lots of date fields of known name pattern(s), I set up a [regex dynamic template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#match-pattern):

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "timeSuffix": {
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "match_pattern": "regex",
            "match": "^(.*Time)|(.*At)$",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

and as I insert docs which contain an arbitrary number of date-like fields:

```
POST myindex/_doc
{
  "createdAt": "2020-01-01 00:00:00",
  "modifiedTime": "2020-01-01 00:00:00"
}
```

the mappings for them are dynamically established.

It's then verifiable w/

```
GET myindex/_mapping
```

Comment: This is alright for the Elasticsearch part. And for only writing into Elasticsearch that would be enough.
But Spring Data Elasticsearch needs the format information to parse the returned documents into the Java objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the formatting issue by adding a custom conversion for java.util.Date type like so:

```
    @Bean
    @Override
    public ElasticsearchCustomConversions elasticsearchCustomConversions() {
        return new ElasticsearchCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(new DateToElasticStringFormat()));
    }

    @WritingConverter
    static class DateToElasticStringFormat implements Converter<Date, String> {

        @Override
        public String convert(Date source) {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
            String dateString = format.format(source);
            return dateString;
        }
    }
```

Now elastic recognizes the dates.